# "Error: Missing required module 'CryptorRSA'" after importing Swift framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift project with a target that we'll call 'ProjectTarget'. ProjectTarget depends on this 'CryptorRSA' framework, which was added to the project using Swift Package Manager.

[image]

[image]

CryptorRSA is imported into a few files (via 'import CryptorRSA') within ProjectTarget and everything is working swimmingly. ProjectTarget is then exported as a framework and imported into an Objective-C app. Now, the Obj-C app which is trying to utilize the ProjectTarget framework is saying "Missing required module 'CryptorRSA'". I added the CryptorRSA package directly to the Obj-C app via Swift Package Manager and that did not solve the issue.

It's probably worth mentioning that this was not an issue prior to Xcode 13. Any help would be much appreciated!

I've already checked several related posts on SO, including:

[Swift app: “Missing required module” when importing framework that imports static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757417/swift-app-missing-required-module-when-importing-framework-that-imports-stati)

[Xcode: missing required module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306779/xcode-missing-required-module-error)

[Swift Project: "Missing Required Modules" when import a modular framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085217/swift-project-missing-required-modules-when-import-a-modular-framework)

Comment: Are you getting error in runtime or in compile time?

Comment: @ManWithBear Compile